# Bounding $\mathbb E(X|\mathcal F_s) - \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F_t)$ on Brownian filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, quadratic-variation

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be a Brownian motion, $\{F_t\}_{t\in [0;T]}$ the filtration generated by $W$, augmented with the nullsets. Let $X \in L^\infty(\mathcal F_T)$. I want to prove that the difference
$$
\vert \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F_s) - \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F_t) \vert
$$
is small (in whatever sense) if $\vert s-t \vert$ is small.

Intuitively, only very little information is added to the one $\sigma$-field in order to obtain the other one. Moreover, the Brownian motion has no jumps. This is why I think that the difference should be small, but I don't know how to approach that formally.

Some statement like
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac 1 h \mathbb E\Big( \big( \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F_{t+h}) - \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F_t) \big)^2 \Big)
\in \mathbb R
$$
would be great, but maybe less would also be enough, it depends.

Comment: Well two observations first $X_t=E[X|\mathcal{F}_t]$ is a martingale (as X is a.s. bounded by hypothesis), second the predictable representation property seems then to hold. So $X_t= X_0+\int_0^t \xi_sdW_s$ for some suitable process $\xi_t$ so this should lead to the following result $\xi_t^2$ under some general conditions using Itô's isometry.

Comment: Thanks. By Itô isometry, we would obtain $\mathbb E(|X_t-X_s|^2) = \mathbb E(|\int_s^t \xi_u \mathrm dW_u|^2) = \mathbb E(\int_s^t (\xi_u)^2 \mathrm du)$. However, what do we know about $\xi$? For the desired limit property in the end of my question, we would need something like $\xi \in \mathcal L^4$, which is not obvious. @TheBridge

Comment: Sorry it's that came to my mind PRP is not constructive only an existence result, to go beyond that you'll need to know something about $X$, maybe Malliavin calculus can come in handy too.

Comment: @TheBridge But $X_t = E[X|\mathcal{F}_t]$ is a martingale wrt a Browian filtration!! So it must be continuous a.s.. Depending on what the OP means by "in whatever sense", this might answer the question.

Comment: @Tom, at least I did not mean it pathwise, but something like $L^1$ or in probability. Sorry, I should have mentioned that explicitly.